# Liferay ant deploy failed

Tags: deployment, build, liferay

I am trying to deploy my first "hello-world"-portlet for Liferay
but I get a "BUILD FAILED" when deploying it.

My folders look like this:

```
D:\[Code Home]\bundles\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2

and 

D:\[Code Home]\plugins\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets
```

My build.[username].properties file contains this:

```
app.server.portal.dir = D:\\[Code Home]\\bundles\\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\\tomcat-    7.0.42\\webapps\\ROOT
app.server.lib.global.dir = D:\\[Code Home]\\bundles\\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\\lib\\ext
app.server.deploy.dir = D:\\[Code Home]\\bundles\\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\\tomcat-7.0.42\\webapps
app.server.type = tomcat
app.server.dir = D:\\[Code Home]\\bundles\\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\\tomcat-7.0.42
```

When deploying the portlet I get this:

```
D:\[Code Home]\plugins\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets>ant deploy
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; sup
port was removed in 8.0
Buildfile: D:\[Code Home]\plugins\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\build.xml


deploy:

BUILD FAILED
D:\[Code Home]\plugins\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common-plugins.xml:57: The
following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\[Code Home]\plugins\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:1387: The follow
ing error occurred while executing this line:
D:\[Code Home]\plugins\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:1392: The follow
ing error occurred while executing this line:
D:\[Code Home]\plugins\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:235: The followi
ng error occurred while executing this line:
D:\[Code Home]\plugins\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:993: The followi
ng error occurred while executing this line:
D:\[Code Home]\plugins\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:299: The followi
ng error occurred while executing this line:
D:\[Code Home]\plugins\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:1766: The follow
ing error occurred while executing this line:
D:\[Code Home]\plugins\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:175: D:\[Code Ho
me]\bundles\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\lib\ext does not exist.

Total time: 0 seconds

D:\[Code Home]\plugins\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets>
```

any idea where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing `auto.deploy.dir` value.
Here is my build.properties values.

```
app.server.type=tomcat
app.server.parent.dir=/home/maleen/workspace/liferay

app.server.tomcat.dir=${app.server.parent.dir}/tomcat-7.0.40
app.server.tomcat.deploy.dir=${app.server.tomcat.dir}/webapps
app.server.tomcat.lib.global.dir=${app.server.tomcat.dir}/lib/ext
app.server.tomcat.portal.dir=${app.server.tomcat.dir}/webapps/ROOT

auto.deploy.dir=${app.server.parent.dir}/deploy
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says

```
D:\[Code Home]\bundles\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\lib\ext does not exist.
```

Does it? If not: You need to either create it (e.g. unzip a bundle at that location) or configure your build.*username*.properties - what's this?

Look at build.properties - you'll find many values configured in there. Just like with other property files in Liferay, you should identify the value that you want to change from the default, create a file named build.*username*.properties (replace with your actual username) and override the value that you'd like to change - e.g. `app.server.parent.dir` is a good candidate to point to your unzipped bundle.

Note that Java8 is not yet officially supported by Liferay: This is a portal that runs on so many existing application server that it's a bit slower in adopting new environments. That's not to say that it won't work - only if you run into Java8 related problems, you might want to try Java7, and be slow to adopt the new features so that you can easily backport.